# fixture 'driver' not found when ot exist in my code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in selenium Python the fixture is not found in my code but it exists in conftest.py
Can someone help with the problem?

But when I copy this fixture in the test.py file it works. The connftest.py file in main directory

```html
conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of pytest (7.4.0) - they implemented following feature ([from here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/changelog.html)):

> #11043: When --confcutdir is not specified, and there is no config file present, the conftest cutoff directory (--confcutdir) is now set
> to the rootdir. Previously in such cases, conftest.py files would be
> probed all the way to the root directory of the filesystem. If you are
> badly affected by this change, consider adding an empty config file to
> your desired cutoff directory, or explicitly set --confcutdir.

It seems like this caused your error. You need to [determine rootdir](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/customize.html#rootdir) - for example you shall create an empty `pytest.ini` file in your project root directory.